# When is a symmetric matrix $A ∈\Bbb R^{3×3}$ with three distinct eigenvalues equal to $A^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

How do you find a symmetric matrix $A ∈\Bbb R^{3×3}$, knowing that:

- $A^n$ $= A$ for some $n > 1$
- $A$ has three distinct eigenvalues
- and we are given two (orthogonal) eigenvectors $[1, 2, 2]^T$ and $[2, 1, −2]^T$.

The problem specifies that there are several possible solutions and I need to compute only one of them. However, I don't see any possible solution. I'm stuck here:

If $A^n$ $= A$, then $D^n$ $=D$, then its eigenvalues to the power of n are equal to themselves. I can think of only $0$ and $1$ to satisfy this property, but the problem asks for three distinct eigenvalues. What is another possible distinct eigenvalue?

I have also derived an expression for the third eigenvector, which is $[y+4z, y, z]^T$, but this doesn't quite help. Especially as we can choose any real values for $y$ and $z$, which basically means that there are infinitely many solutions for the matrix $A$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Another possible eigenvalue is $-1$, as $(-1)^n=-1$ for odd $n$.

Comment: If I understand correctly "for some n>1",  it actually means "for any n>1". Or are we allowed to choose n? Then we may choose n=2 and eigenvalue -1 would not work.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Eli88 The meaning of "for some" requires the existential quantifier. That is, your first bulleted item is "$(\exists n)[A^n=A].$ Note that the meaning of existential quantifier is not that you get to choose whatever n you want to, instead it means there is at least one n which has that property. It is up to you to exhibit such an n in order to establish that bulleted item.

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact only $6$ such matrices, corresponding to the $6$ permutations of $\{0,1,-1\}$. Each such matrix $A$ would then have $A^n=A$ for all odd $n$.

The third eigenvector $(x, y, z)$ must be orthogonal to the other two. So, $x+2y+2z=0$ and $2x+y-2z=0$. Solving this, one gets $y=-x$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}x$, so the third eigenvector must be of the form $(x, -x, \frac{1}{2}x)$. Any nonzero scalar multiple of an eigenvector is again an eigenvector (corresponding to the same eigenvalue), so $(1, -1, \frac{1}{2})$ is an eigenvector.

The given eigenvectors, however, are not orthonormal unit vectors. Each eigenvector may be divided by its length to get a unit vector. One has $||(1, 2, 2)||=||(2, 1, -2)||=3$ and $||(1, -1, \frac{1}{2})||=\frac{3}{2}$.

So, the resulting unit vectors are $(\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{3})$, $(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, -\frac{2}{3})$, and $(\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$.

It thus follows that the orthogonal diagonalization of $A$ is given by $\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&-\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}&-\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}D\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&-\frac{2}{3}\\\frac{2}{3}&-\frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{3}\end{pmatrix}^T$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues $0$ and $\pm{1}$ on the diagonal.

Comment: Shouldn't be one of the matrices in the diagonalization transpose of the other?

Comment: @user376343 I have included the corresponding orthonormal unit vectors that form an orthogonal matrix (with its inverse equal to its transpose).